# I am unable to send a post request in C++ using socket programming

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

I am trying to send a post request in C++ using socket programming, but the request doesnt seem to get executed. I am unsure of whether or not the syntax of the POST request is correct or not.
Here is the request that I am sending

```
string payload = "";
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
{
    payload += (data[i].first + "=" + data[i].second);
    if(i<(data.size()-1))
        payload += "&";
}
string request_string = "POST ";
request_string += path;
request_string += " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
request_string += ("Host: " + base_url + "\r\n");
request_string += ("Accept: */*\r\n");
request_string += ("Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
request_string += ("Content-Length: " + to_string(payload.length()));
request_string += "\r\n";

request_string += payload;
```

Here base_url=`httpbin.org` and path =`\post` and data is a pair `("ef","gh")`
Which when printed on the console becomes

```
POST /post HTTP/1.1
Host: httpbin.org
Accept: */*
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 5

ef=gh
```

The entire code is

```
string request::post(string url,vector<pair<string,string>> data){

    char buffer[10000];
    int data_len;
    string response;
    int result;

    string base_url = "";
    string path = "";
    bool flag = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < url.length(); i++)
    {
        if (url[i] == '/')
            flag = false;
        if (flag)
            base_url += url[i];
        else
            path += url[i];
    }

    string payload = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        payload += (data[i].first + "=" + data[i].second);
        if(i<(data.size()-1))
            payload += "&";
    }
    string request_string = "POST ";
    request_string += path;
    request_string += " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    request_string += ("Host: " + base_url + "\r\n");
    request_string += ("Accept: */*\r\n");
    request_string += ("Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
    request_string += ("Content-Length: " + to_string(payload.length()));
    request_string += "\r\n\r\n";

    request_string += payload;

    cout << request_string << endl;

    struct hostent *host = gethostbyname(base_url.c_str());
    SOCKADDR_IN server;
    server.sin_port = htons(80);
    server.sin_family = host->h_addrtype;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long *)host->h_addr);
    memset(&server.sin_zero, 0, 8);

    SOCKET sock;
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    logger("Unable to create a socket", "Successfully created a socket", result);

    result = connect(sock, (SOCKADDR *)(&server), sizeof(server));
    logger("Unable to connect to the server", "Successfully connected to the server", result, sock);

    result = send(sock, request_string.c_str(), strlen(request_string.c_str()), 0);
    logger("Unable to send the request", "Successfully sent the request", result, sock);

    while ((data_len = recv(sock, buffer, 10000, 0)) > 0)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (buffer[i] >= 32 || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r')
        {
            response += buffer[i];
            i += 1;
        }
    }
    cout << endl
         << "***********************" << endl;
    cout << "Response" << endl;
    cout << "***********************" << endl;
    return response;

}
```

where the url is `httpbin.org/post`.

Somebody kindly point out the mistake I am making

Comment: Your `Content-Length` is missing a trailing `\r\n`.  And you should not be appending `\r\n\r\n` after the `payload` at all. The rest of the request looks fine, so if you are still having trouble after making these corrections, then it may be a problem in how you are connecting to the server and sending the `request_string`, but you did not show that code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I did the changes you mentioned, but it doesnt seem to work still. I have updated the code in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of problems with your code.

- You are not checking `gethostbyname()` for failure (you should use `getaddrinfo()` instead), or validating that `host->h_addrtype` is `AF_INET` only.
- You are not checking `socket()`, `connect()`, or `send()` for failures, either.
- You are not accounting for the possibility that `send()` may not be able to send the entire request in one call.  You need to call it in a loop until the entire request has been sent.
- Your `while` loop doesn't account for `data_len` at all, and thus will go out of bounds of the `buffer` and likely crash when it eventually tries to access invalid memory.
- And frankly, your parser is just [wholly inadequate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14421507/65863) for a viable HTTP client.
- Most importantly, you are expecting the server to close the connection at the end of the response, but you are requesting `HTTP/1.1`, which keeps the connection open by default, and you are not requesting the connection be closed. So `recv()` will end up blocking after the response is done (at least for awhile, until the server times out), so you won't see your `response` string being printed to the console.  Try adding `"Connection: close\r\n"` to your request headers, or else have the request ask for `HTTP/1.0` instead.

Try this:

```cpp
string request::post(const string &url, const vector<pair<string,string>> &data)
{
    char buffer[10000];
    int data_len;
    string response;
    int result;

    string::size_type pos = url.find('/');
    string base_url = url.substr(0, pos);
    string path = url.substr(pos);

    string payload;
    if (!data.empty())
    {
        payload = (data[0].first + "=" + data[0].second);
        for (size_t i = 1; i < data.size(); ++i)
        {
            payload += ("&" + data[i].first + "=" + data[i].second);
        }
    }

    string request_string = "POST ";
    request_string += path;
    request_string += " HTTP/1.1\r\n"; // or HTTP/1.0
    request_string += ("Host: " + base_url + "\r\n");
    request_string += "Accept: */*\r\n";
    request_string += "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    request_string += ("Content-Length: " + to_string(payload.size()) + "\r\n");
    request_string += "Connection: close\r\n"; // omit this if using HTTP/1.0
    request_string += "\r\n";
    request_string += payload;

    cout << request_string << endl;

    struct hostent *host = gethostbyname(base_url.c_str());
    if (!host)
    {
        logger("Unable to query hostname");
        return "";
    }
    logger("Successfully queried hostname");

    if (host->h_addrtype != AF_INET)
    {
        logger("hostname does not have IPv4 address");
        return "";
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN server = {};
    server.sin_port = htons(80);
    server.sin_family = host->h_addrtype;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long *)host->h_addr);

    SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sock < 0)
    {
        logger("Unable to create a socket");
        return "";
    }
    logger("Successfully created a socket");

    result = connect(sock, (SOCKADDR *)(&server), sizeof(server));
    if (result < 0)
    {
        logger("Unable to connect to the server");
        close(sock);
        return "";
    }
    logger("Successfully connected to the server");

    const char *preq = request_string.c_str();
    data_len = request_string.size();
    do
    {
        result = send(sock, preq, data_len, 0);
        if (result < 0)
        {
            logger("Unable to send the request");
            close(sock);
            return "";
        }
        preq += result;
        data_len -= result;
    }
    while (data_len > 0);
    logger("Successfully sent the request");

    while ((data_len = recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0)) > 0)
    {
        int i = 0;
        do
        {
            if (buffer[i] >= 32 || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r')
            {
                response += buffer[i];
            }
            ++i;
        }
        while (i < data_len);
    }

    if (data_len < 0)
    {
        logger("Unable to read the response");
        close(sock);
        return "";
    }

    cout << endl
         << "***********************" << endl;
    cout << "Response" << endl;
    cout << "***********************" << endl;

    return response;
}
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot for the suggestions, I will keep them in mind from now on. Could you also guide me to some good resources from where I can all of this web requests in C++, as there seems to be a serious lack of such resources. I want to make my own requests library in C++ @RemyLebeau